# grunt-usemin with vendor .min.js files

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

How do you use usemin together with .min.js files and not mangle them?
When I run it with the standard config, or with grunt-usemin-uglifynew I get an Angular error from a mangled variable

But if I follow up with a simple concat of the .min.js files, it works fine

```
concat:
  vendor:
    dest: '<%= BUILD_DIR %>/javascripts/vendor-BODY.min.js'
    src: [ 
       '<%= BUILD_DIR %>/components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js',
       '<%= BUILD_DIR %>/components/angular/angular.min.js',
       ...
    ]
```

Comment: Have you tried pre-minifying your scripts with the Grunt task [ngmin](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin) before running usemin?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't discovered it before. it sounds like it should do the trick.